# Issue with state mismatch on registration using react native app auth

Tags: react-native, react-redux, appauth

Im wondering if anyone has some experience in this issue.

I am getting a state mismatch error when trying to register using react native app auth.

React native version: "0.67.3",
React native app auth version: "^6.4.3",

```
[Error: State mismatch, expecting Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXs but got Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXsregistration in authorization response <OIDAuthorizationResponse: 0x6000017b29e0, authorizationCode: 4d890080dde715cedddf076e5ffb4fc8aaeeb22d4ebca281d4c7d74df377607c, state: "Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXsregistration", accessToken: "(null)", accessTokenExpirationDate: (null), tokenType: (null), idToken: "(null)", scope: "(null)", additionalParameters: {
}, request: <OIDAuthorizationRequest: 0x600001f7c000, request: https://api.staging.com/oauth/authorize?nonce=iJxSOkt6tGToBUndfg3n0V4B_ZZNBIm8TwbTg18EGOo&response_type=code&scope=trusted%20public%20refresh_token&code_challenge=iNlpVkj7UDpXyu5wBlMuln41huSZcGsdWEQ9fYLtcuU&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=someredirectt&client_id=9dc36c26d21198f5c97f12b34be3cce7a37e5abdc323fcc0b205a898d22994f7&state=Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXs>>]
```

the code that generates the request is so:

```
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
  issuer: TEMP_API,
  clientId: OAUTH_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
  redirectUrl: OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL,
  clientSecret: OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scopes: ['trusted', 'public', 'refresh_token'],
};

const configForSignup = {
  ...config,
  additionalParameters: {
    response_mode: 'query'
  },
};

export const authorizeOauthUser = (
  {
    isSignup,
  },
) => async () => {
  try {
    const oAuthConfig = isSignup ? configForSignup : config;
    const result = await authorize(oAuthConfig);
    console.log({result});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({error})
  }
};
```

I have looked at the following [ticket](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/694) and implemented the suggested response_mode: "query" but to no avail.

Im not quite sure of the 'registration' at the end of the expected token [Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXsregistration] is appended to the token itself and thats why its mismatching or if its just spaced strangely.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit old but the response mentions explicitly **state: "Z2-6m8_T7FcIlbG9wep3Xb2wvgsylbd9M54iiX97rXsregistration"**

I guess you are trying to connect to a custom authentication system, you should log that as a bug. The state parameter in the response should exactly match the one from the request.

The state is not the token, it is just a random ID to make sure that the response is received for the right request.